# Can Twitter Analytics show the number of clicks from Tweets back to my website?

Tags: analytics, tracking, twitter

I have just added "conversion tracking"  `https://analytics.twitter.com/accounts/[xxxxxxx]/conversion_tracking`

Sadly after adding the JS code to my website I still can not see where I can view which of my Tweets has made a "click back to my website".  Can this indeed be done via Twitter Analytics or is it for something else?